# nested for loop faster after profile guided optimization but with higher cache misses

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, profiling

I have a program that has at its heart a 2D array in the form of a

```
std::vector<std::vector< int > > grid
```

And there's a simple double for loop going on that goes somewhat like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<N-1; ++i)
    for(int j=1; j<N-1; ++j)
        sum += grid[i][j-1] + grid[i][j+1] + grid[i-1][j] + grid[i+1][j] + grid[i][j]*some_float;
```

With `g++ -O3` it runs pretty fast, but for further optimization I profiled with callgrind and see a L1 Cache miss of about 37%, and 33% for LL which is a lot but not too surprising considering the random-ish nature of the computation. So I do a profile-guided optimization a la

```
g++ -fprofile-generate -O3 ...
./program
g++ -fprofile-use -O3 ...
```

and the program runs about 48% faster! But the puzzling part: The cache misses have even increased! L1 data cache miss is now 40%, LL same.

How can that be? There are no conditionals in the loop for which prediction could have been optimised and the cache misses are even higher. Yet it is faster.

**edit**: Alright, here's the sscce: http://pastebin.com/fLgskdQG . Play around with the N for different runtime. Compiled via

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -sscce.cpp
```

on gcc 4.8.1 under linux.

profile-guided optimization with the commands above. The Callgrind stuff is done with a g++ -g switch and `valgrind --tool=callgrind --simulate-cache=yes ./sscce`

Comment: Wow. I did not knew you can do profile guided optimization with gcc.

Comment: Faster code will give the prefetcher a harder time.  PGO can improve branch prediction, not L1 data cache hit rate, muddy how that could improve on simple loops though.  Encourage answers by posting assembly code.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I was in Germany in 2002 or so when profile guided optimisation was first introduced in gcc. It wasn't that fantastic, but some cases gave quite a bit of improvement even then. So it's not exactly new... :)

Comment: You don't mention exactly which version of gcc you've been using...

Comment: gcc 4.8.1 under linux

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 does not show any performance improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed only one significant difference between assembly codes generated with or without PGO. Without PGO `sum` variable is spilled from register to memory, once per inner loop iteration. This writing variable to memory and loading it back might in theory slow down things very significantly. Fortunately modern processors optimize it with store-to-load forwarding, so that slowdown is not so big. Still Intel's optimization manual does not recommend to spill floating point variables to memory, especially when they are computed by long-latency operations, like floating point multiplication.

What is really puzzling here is why GCC needs PGO to avoid spilling register to memory. It is enough unused floating point registers, and even without PGO compiler could get all information necessary for proper optimization from single source file...

These unnecessary load/store operations explain not only why PGO code is faster, but also why it increases percentage of cache misses. Without PGO register is always spilled to the same location in memory, so this additional memory access increases both number of memory accesses and number of cache hits, while it does not change number of cache misses. With PGO we have less memory accesses but same amount of cache misses, so their percentage increases.

Comment: I did some more tinkering and found that this matter is very volatile, and performance changes between operating systems and compiler versions. But your comment probably explains this. Thanks!

Comment: @Basti have you tried a single vector and address cells with `(row * columnCount) + column`. That way the whole grid will be stored in a single memory block instead of in several fragmented blocks for each row.